# Imported json library Java, but still getting JSON cannot be resolved error

Tags: java, json, import

I started coding on leetcode and then opened it in playground and put that code in my local and imported the json jar, but am still seeing the error that Json cannot be resolved.

error line: 
return Json.value(input).toString();

I have tried the both import jars

import org.json.*;
import org.json.simple.*;

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
public static String stringToString(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
    return "null";
        }
        return Json.value(input).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run this on leetcode, the jar should be actually present on your application classpath in order for import to work. As a test, try running your code in some IDE like eclipse or Intellij. It will prompt you at compile time about the error.

Comment: I ran this code on leetcode and worked fine, now when put that code in eclipse, am getting that error. I have imported the jar files too.

Answer (score 0):

Json not available in org.json. You may use JSONObject to parse json string like this

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(
  "{\"city\":\"chicago\",\"name\":\"jon doe\",\"age\":\"22\"}"
);
```

See full example [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json)